# Raise event upon population of DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have a Form in which I have to populate DataGrid. The source for this DataGrid comes from another class.

I need to populate the DataGrid through Raising Event in that class in which i'm getting Datatable.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class ExcelReader

    Private WithEvents tmrRead As New Timer

    Dim fullpath As String = ""

    Public Sub ExcelReader()
        tmrRead.Interval = 2000
        tmrRead.Start()
    End Sub


    Public Sub TimerTick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrRead.Tick
        Dim DT As New DataTable

        Dim path As String = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory).ToString).ToString + "\ExcelHotReader\"

    Dim file1 As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xls")
    Dim file2 As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xlsx")
    If file1.Count <> 0 Or file2.Count <> 0 Then
        tmrRead.Stop()
    End If

        If file1.Count <> 0 Then
            fullpath = file1(0).ToString
        End If

        If file2.Count <> 0 Then
            fullpath = file2(0).ToString
        End If

        Dim DT As New DataTable
        Dim cn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim cmd As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "data source=" & fullpath & ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")

        cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", cn)
        cn.Open()
        cmd.Fill(DT)
        cn.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

After cn.Close() the event should be raised with Datatable. This event need to be captured by the form to populate DataGrid.

Comment: A side note, if you want to support both "xls" and "xlsx" you need ACE.12.0 oledb provider not Jet.4.0

Comment: If you want to call a function after cn.Close(), why not calling it directly? Events are associated to controls with "dynamic behaviours" which wouldn't be tracked otherwise. But your cn.Close() is pretty static: it is written in a line of your code; so there is no difficulty in calling directly the given method after this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the declaration of the Event inside the ExcelReader class and call it at the end of your code using the RaiseEvent

```
Public Class ExcelReader
    Public Event DataTableLoaded(ByVal dt As DataTable)
    .......

        Using cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.12.0;.......")
        Using cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", cn)
            cn.Open()
            cmd.Fill(DT)
            RaiseEvent DataTableLoaded(DT)
        End Using
        End Using
    ....
End Class
```

Then the calling code declares (globally) an instance of the ExcelReader class with the keyword WithEvents

```
Public Dim WithEvents readerTableFromExcel = New ExcelReader()
```

Finally the declaration of the methods that handle the event (the event sink)

```
Public Sub DataTableFromExcel(ByVal dt As System.Data.DataTable) _
           Handles readerTableFromExcel.DataTableLoaded
    MsgBox("Table loaded")
End Sub
```

As a final note, I would use a different method to start the reading of the Excel file (for example a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class seems more appropriate than a TimerTick event)

If you need to deepen your knowledge of events, [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=23020) seems a good summary of what is important to know

Comment: +1 because your answer is really detailed and gives an elegant solution to the OP's question. But I don't see the motivation of complicating things so much here: what is the problem with a simple call to the desired function after cn.Close() without involving events at all?

Comment: @varocarbas I don't know. I think that only the OP could respond to your question. But, perhaps, seeing its use of the TimerTick event, probably he doesn't want its gui remain blocked while the table is loading.